# How to webscrape multiple pages efficiently using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How long does it normally take to web-scrape multiple pages? I have kept it running and have not gotten output. Currently it is only scraping one url. I plan to scrape 5 urls. Does this mean my loop is just stuck in an infinite loop?

Additionally, if anyone knows how to make my j loop more efficient instead of accessing the tag elements one by one it would be great. I assume that is one method I can increase the efficiency and speed of my script. Any help is appreciated.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Import the necessary modules to run the script. 
If error, use pip to install modules
'''
import pandas as pd #Data analysis and manipulation tool
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request #Package that helps in opening URLS
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup #Package to pull data out from HTML and XML files
import ssl #TLS/SSL wrapper for accessing OS socket

'''
Use headers to prevent getting blocked by websites when scraping high volumes of data frequently
''' 
def get_headers():
   #Headers
   headers={'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
           'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
           'cache-control':'max-age=0',
           'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
           'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'}
   return headers

'''
Create SSL wrapper and check connection
'''
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
count = 1 # for pagination


'''
Create a list holder
'''
info = {
        'name': [],
        'date': [],
        'address': [],
        'district': [],
        'city': [],
        'price': [],
        'area_sqm': [],
        'rooms': [],
        'floor': [],
        'commission_year': [],
        'total_floors': [],
        'garage': [],
        'balcony': [],
        'windows': [],
        'windows_type': [],
        'door_type': [],
        'leasing': [],
        'description': [],
        'link': []
        }

urls = ['https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/4-r/']

'''
Loop to scrape multiple pages of data.
Change while count integer to indiate how many pages to scrape.
'''

for i in urls:
    count=1
    y=i
    while(count<2):
        http_request = Request(i, headers=get_headers())
        html_file = urlopen(http_request)
        html_text = html_file.read()
        soup = bsoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
        
        for tag in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'list-announcement-block'}):
            name = tag.find('a', attrs={'itemprop':'name'})
            description = tag.find('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__description'})
            link = name['href']
            date = tag.find('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__date'})
            price = tag.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop':'price'})
            price2 = tag.find('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__price _premium'})
            
            info['name'].append(name['content'] if name else 'N/A')
            info['description'].append(description.get_text().strip() if description else 'N/A')
            info['link'].append('http://www.unegui.mn'+link if link else 'N/A')
            info['date'].append(date.get_text().strip() if date else 'N/A')
            info['price'].append(price['content'] if price else price2.get_text().strip())
            
            for j in info['link']:
                for litag in soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class':'chars-column'}):
                  floor = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[0]
                  balcony = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[1]
                  year = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[2]
                  garage = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[3]
                  window_type = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[4]
                  building_floor = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[5]
                  door_type = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[6]
                  area_sqm = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[7]
                  floor = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[8]
                  leasing = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[9]
                  district = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[10]
                  windows_num = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[11]
                  location = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[12]
                  
                  info['floor'].append(floor.get_text().strip() if date else 'N/A')
                    
# Go to next page
count=count+1
page = '?page='+str(count)
i=y+page
     
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(info['name'], info['description'], info['link'], info['date'], info['price'], info['floor'])),columns=['Name', 'Description', 'Link', 'Date', 'Price', 'Floor'])
print(df)
```

Comment: add some status printing to your loops to see whether or not it is progressing....

Comment: I tried adding some print functions right before it goes to the next page, but it never printed. How and where should I put some status printing in your opinion? Thank you.

Comment: Doing all those `litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})` and just getting 1 element each time definitely not efficient.  You should save it in a variable and use that; something like `tmp = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'}); floor = tmp[0]; balcony = tmp[1] ...`

Comment: You're incrementing *count* outside of the loop (which it will never get to) - i.e., it will always be equal to 1

Comment: @LohmarASHAR I think I tried doing that before, and encountered some problems which is why I did it so inefficiently like this. I'll try it again and fix it.

Comment: @BrutusForcus I realized that when my code kept running. I'm just trying to figure out how I can implement 2e0byo's suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the floor information, you need to access the href for each property. The code below runs very slowly. This is not due to the performance of Python but is a result of poor response times from the multitude of hyperlinks that we have to visit.

One enhancement over your code is that my answer accounts for all known pages. The numbers of pages cannot be predetermined. However, if we try to access (for example) page 12 and page 12 doesn't exist then we will be directed to the highest known page. In this example that's page 11. By keeping track of the last page visited, we can work out when to break out of the loop.

Hope this helps:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import pandas as pd
import re


def main():
    page = 0
    name = []
    description = []
    link = []
    date = []
    price = []
    floor = []
    
    BASE = 'https://www.unegui.mn'
    URL = f'{BASE}/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/4-r/?page='
    COLUMNS=['Name', 'Description', 'Link', 'Date', 'Price', 'Floor']
    with requests.Session() as session:
        while True:
            (r := session.get(f'{URL}{page+1}')).raise_for_status()
            m = re.search('.*page=(\d+)$', r.url)
            if m and int(m.group(1)) == page:
                break
            page += 1
            print(f'Processing page {page}')
            soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')
            for tag in soup.findAll('div', class_='list-announcement-block'):
                _name = tag.find('a', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'})
                name.append(_name.get('content', 'N/A'))
                if (_link := _name.get('href', None)):
                    link.append(f'{BASE}{_link}')
                    (_r := session.get(link[-1])).raise_for_status()
                    _floor = BS(_r.text, 'lxml').find('span', class_='value-chars')
                    floor.append(_floor.get_text().strip() if _floor else 'N/A')
                description.append(tag.find('div', class_='announcement-block__description').get_text().strip())
                date.append(tag.find('div', class_='announcement-block__date').get_text().split(',')[0].strip())
                if (_price := tag.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'price'})) is None:
                    _price = tag.find('div', class_='announcement-block__price _premium')
                price.append(_price.get_text().strip() if _price else 'N/A')
        df = pd.DataFrame(zip(name, description, link, date, price, floor), columns=COLUMNS)
        print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your input. Can I add a list of URLs? I need to scrape 5 urls that are /1-r/, /2-r/, /3-r/, /4-r/, /5-r/, where r stands for bedroom basically. Meaning I am trying to scrape 5 different bedroom # searches.

Comment: And my price column seems to not be working. When I put ['content'] it says NoneType object is not subscriptable. Any ideas?

Comment: I wasn't planning on re-writing your entire application. Sorry

Comment: I was just trying to understand part of your code. For example, I am trying to get more values from the span class beyond just the floor column. Would I have to create a new _r := variable for each column or can I somehow get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd element somehow? Where the 1st element would be floor, 2nd would be address/etc. These elements are all in an span list.

Comment: This line *_floor = BS(_r.text, 'lxml').find('span', class_='value-chars')* will find the first occurrence. Use find_all to, guess what, find all occurrences. find_all will return a list which let's call *spanlist*. Then you can access *spanlist[0]*, *spanlist[1]* etc

Comment: Thank you. I realized I could implement the find_all function I used in my code previously and was able to get my desired data. I have just been stuck on how to include a list of urls into your code. So it scrapes multiple urls (l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/4-r/?page=', l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/5-r/?page=', etc), and multiple pages for each url.

Answer (score 3):

There are some probably redundant loops going on here:

```py
floor = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[0]
balcony = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})[1]
...
```

Could be more efficiently written as:

```py
value_chars = litag.find_all(attrs={'class':'value-chars'})
floor, balcony, ... = value_chars
```

I.e. don't call the `find_all` every time. However, it's not clear what you actually *do* with your variables when you get them.  Did you mean to put them in `info`?  And if so, why overwrite them every time?

### Infinte Looping

Here is your while loop, stripped of content:

```py
count = 0
while count < 2:
    ...

count += 1
```

Do you see the problem?  `count` is never modified inside the loop, so the loop will run for ever.  Whilst indenting the `count += 1` would fix it, use a for loop:

```py
for count in range(1,3):
    ...
```

or more sensibly here:

```py
for page in range(1,3):
    ...
```

given that that's apparently what count *is*.  Note that your algorithm implies doing this inside the outer `for url in urls` loop, but you don't actually do so.

### Avoiding redundant scraping

If you don't need a value, don't scrape it.  Currently you look up and then throw away all kinds of things.  But the main problem is just the inifite loop.

### Progress

A `print(f"Currently scraping page {count}")` at the top of your while loop would have showed you what was happening.  In general when testing loops, print something every time they run, so you can see *what* is running.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not responding immediately. Thank you for your input. Yes I wanted to put the scrapped litag loop values into the df DataFrame. I am still confusing where I should be putting the for loop. I assume at the top, but then I am unsure what I am supposed to do with my urls list and my http_request .

Comment: your current structure is `for url in url_list: for page in range(1,3): do_stuff()` which is fine (except that indentation errors have broken it).  If you're really stuck on how to get it going, it might be worth opening another question with a very basic (even psuedo-code) setup.  But really here you just need to think logically, break the problem up, and start with the innermost block (scraping one page), and then move up bit by bit (how do I concatenate two pages? etc) until it works.  SO isn't really for step-by-step help with that, but you might get some input on a decent forum :)